# Breadcrumb Schema using Google Tags

Tags: json, schema, google-tag-manager, breadcrumbs

I am slowly learning about schema's and want to implement breadcrumbs. I am creating my schema's using Google Tags.

Question: Do I need to create a schema for every page (which will be done eventually anyway) and add the breadcrumbs to each? Or do I create 1 new tag that has the breadcrumbs for all pages? I am struggling to find out whether I need separate schema's for each page or if it all goes under one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you can append the schema suggested by google in a single aspx file where breadcrumb format is used commonly for all pages.
but im not sure about the exact format of schema.
Refer : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb